# Postgres `createuser` command not working

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create a new user. I am getting same error consistently. I tried lot of solutions given online but no luck.

I am using

> Postgres 9.5
>   Ubuntu 16.04
>   my username **ravi**

I am trying by this command

```
createuser -e -E sonar -s -U "$(whoami)" -P
```

I am getting an error like this:

> Enter password for new role:
>   Enter it again:  Password:
>   createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ravi"

Comment: You should be running this command under "postgres" user: First, `sudo -u postgres -i`, then `createuser` and arguments. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL

Comment: @JanSamek: `createuser -U postgres ...` should work as well (if the postgres role is allowed to login with a password)